# Modulus - Too big a number for the calculator

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I go about doing this?

$51^{47}$ mod $1537$?

I tried using binary to split it up but in the end, I got $$
51^{47}=1473\cdot 1051\cdot864\cdot1064\cdot51 \mod 1537
$$ which was still to huge to be calculated using the graphic/scientific calculator. Is there any other way I can derive the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the multiplication in steps, reducing mod $1537$ at each step

Comment: even with binary to split the powers, the numbers is still to big to be mod =( @simon s

Comment: You mean your calculator cannot handle numbers in the order of a million?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I think the order is more like a trillion ($1000\cdot 1000\cdot 1000\cdot (864\cdot 51)\approx 1000^{4}$)... that is on the order of $10^{12}$ which is bigger than $2^{32}$.  So if it the calculator stores only 32-bit ints, then it would overflow.

Comment: @TravisJ I already told the OP to do this in steps (as you even put in the answer).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, sorry, my mistake.  You are right.  Each step is on the order of a million and that is very do-able.

Comment: Or, you might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring for a general answer (with this, you may manage using only 10 modular multiplications, unless I am mistaken). By the way, 1537 is a RSA modulus: are you trying to learn RSA? In this case, you should already know this!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, don't do all the multiplication at once.

Assuming $51^{47}=1473\cdot 1051\cdot 864\cdot 1064\cdot 51 \mod 1537$ as you claim, then you can make the final computation by doing:

$a=1473\cdot 1051 \mod 1537$ (make sure that $0\leq a<1537$)

$b=a\cdot 864 \mod 1537$ (make sure that $0\leq b<1537$)

$c=b\cdot 1064 \mod 1537$ (make sure that $0\leq c<1537$)

$d=c\cdot 51 \mod 1537$.

Then, the solution is $d$.